# Site list search/filter

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I have been on this service for a while and it always bothered me that StackExchange does not allow to search/filter the site list. The amount of sites is great, but finding something is really difficult. Does anyone know if there is a particular reason SE does not implement this feature? In my opinion this would be a great improvement to this page UX.

**Implementation example:**

[image]